# Parse csv file with line breaks and additional commas

Tags: parsing, csv

My current csv file looks like the following:

```
field1, field1, field3, field4, field5, field6  
111, John, Doctor, 1A-jrd, ,"Tuft St  
Peoria, IL 54345  
(12.11111, 43.5555)"  
121, Bob, Teacher, 2A-abcd, 345, "Moore Ave  
Boston, MA 23123  
(67.11111,- 49.5567)"  
131, Kyle, Engineer, 3A-bhbh, , "Barnes St  
San Francisco, CA 34654  
(65.11111, 55.985432)"
```

In some cases field5 does not have a value. Also, field6 is within quotes and has line breaks. For example: field6 for the first row of data is actually

```
"Tuft St  
Peoria, IL 54345  
(12.11111, 43.5575)"
```

I need to write a script to parse this file and return 12.111, 43.557 in place of the current value of field6 such that the final csv file will look like

```
field1, field1, field3, field4, field5, field6  
111, John, Doctor, 1A-jrd, , "12.111, 43.555"  
121, Bob, Teacher, 2A-abcd, 345, "67.111,- 49.556"  
131, Kyle, Engineer, 3A-bhbh, , "65.111, 55.985"
```

I have looked at cvsparser but my understanding is that it works only if the entire data row is on one line without any line breaks. Also, I cannot simply use a comma to split the rows because there are addresses which have multiple commas within them. Any suggestions on how I could parse this csv file?

Comment: What language?  In Perl I would be thinking use the Text::CSV module.

Comment: Are the fields in your CSV file really not quoted? That makes it *very* difficult, if not impossible, to parse accurately.

Comment: @Sobrique: Any language would do.

Comment: @rici: Only fields with multiple commas within them have quotes such as field6.

Answer (score 1):

For such ‘unstructured csv’ format you can use [Marpa::R2](https://metacpan.org/release/Marpa-R2), a Perl interface to [Marpa](http://savage.net.au/Marpa.html), a general BNF parser.

The data can be described in [BNF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Backus%E2%80%93Naur_Form) as `this ::= that` (`~` operator defines lexical rules). Parens in `::=` rules, e.g. `(header [\n])` mean ‘don't include in parse result.’

The parser returns a data structure (array of arrays in `[ id, child1, child2 ... ]` format), from which data can be extracted.

You can also define [semantic actions](https://metacpan.org/source/JKEGL/Marpa-R2-3.000000/t/sl_action2.t#L51) as Perl `sub`'s in the same or separate package to process the data.

An example script and its output, based on your data, is below.

script:

```perl
use 5.010;
use strict;
use warnings;

use Data::Dumper;
$Data::Dumper::Indent = 1;
$Data::Dumper::Terse = 1;
$Data::Dumper::Deepcopy = 1;

use Marpa::R2;

my $g = Marpa::R2::Scanless::G->new( { source => \(<<'END_OF_SOURCE'),

    :default ::= action => [ name, value]
    lexeme default = action => [ name, value] latm => 1

    csv ::= (header [\n]) lines

    header ::= column+ separator => column_sep
    column_sep ~ ', '
    column ~ 'field' [1-6]

    lines       ::= line+ separator => [\n]
    line        ::= fields1_5 (',') field6
    field_sep   ~ ','
    fields1_5   ::= field1_5+ separator => field_sep
    field1_5    ~ num | word | code
    field6      ~ address

    num ~ [\d]+
    word ~ [A-Za-z]+
    code  ~ num word '-' word
    address ~ '"' address_chars '"'
    address_chars ~ [^\"]+ #"

    :discard ~ space
    space ~ ' '

END_OF_SOURCE
} );

my $input = <<EOI;
field1, field1, field3, field4, field5, field6
111, John, Doctor, 1A-jrd, ,"Tuft St
Peoria, IL 54345
(12.11111, 43.5555)"
121, Bob, Teacher, 2A-abcd, 345, "Moore Ave
Boston, MA 23123
(67.11111,- 49.5567)"
131, Kyle, Engineer, 3A-bhbh, , "Barnes St
San Francisco, CA 34654
(65.11111, 55.985432)"
EOI

say Dumper ${ $g->parse( \$input, { trace_terminals => 0 } ) };
```

output:

```
[
  'csv',
  [
    'lines',
    [
      'line',
      [
        'fields1_5',
        [
          'field1_5',
          '111'
        ],
        [
          'field1_5',
          'John'
        ],
        [
          'field1_5',
          'Doctor'
        ],
        [
          'field1_5',
          '1A-jrd'
        ]
      ],
      [
        'field6',
        '"Tuft St
Peoria, IL 54345
(12.11111, 43.5555)"'
      ]
    ],
    [
      'line',
      [
        'fields1_5',
        [
          'field1_5',
          '121'
        ],
        [
          'field1_5',
          'Bob'
        ],
        [
          'field1_5',
          'Teacher'
        ],
        [
          'field1_5',
          '2A-abcd'
        ],
        [
          'field1_5',
          '345'
        ]
      ],
      [
        'field6',
        '"Moore Ave
Boston, MA 23123
(67.11111,- 49.5567)"'
      ]
    ],
    [
      'line',
      [
        'fields1_5',
        [
          'field1_5',
          '131'
        ],
        [
          'field1_5',
          'Kyle'
        ],
        [
          'field1_5',
          'Engineer'
        ],
        [
          'field1_5',
          '3A-bhbh'
        ]
      ],
      [
        'field6',
        '"Barnes St
San Francisco, CA 34654
(65.11111, 55.985432)"'
      ]
    ]
  ]
]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't. As you allow commas in field 6, this is a valid file

A,B,C,D,,E
  a,b,c,d,e,f

And you have no way to find out if this file contains one or two entries, as the field 6 for the first data set can be 'E' or 'E \n a,b,c,d,e,f'

Comment: Fields with multiple commas within them like field6 have quotes.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `csv` library for this

```
import csv

with open('myfile.csv') as myfile:
     csv_file = csv.reader(myfile, delimiter = ',')
```

Now you have the rows, do whatever you wish.

Comment: But field6 has additional commas within it. I cannot simply parse on the comma.

Comment: Then use some another delimiter

Answer (score 0):

You need a CSV parser for that sort of data. I would suggest perl and Text::CSV:

Something like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use strict;
use warnings;

use Text::CSV; 

my $csv = Text::CSV -> new( { 'binary' => 1, eol => "\n" } ); 

open ( my $input_fh, '<', "sample.csv" ) or die $!; 

my $header = $csv -> getline ( $input_fh );
$csv -> print ( \*STDOUT, $header );

while ( my $row = $csv -> getline ( $input_fh ) ) { 
    $row -> [5] =~ s,.*\(,\(,ms;
    $csv -> print ( \*STDOUT, $row );
}
```

Given source data of:

```
field1, field1, field3, field4, field5, field6  
111, John, Doctor, 1A-jrd, ,"Tuft St  
Peoria, IL 54345  
(12.11111, 43.5555)"
121, Bob, Teacher, 2A-abcd,345,"Moore Ave  
Boston, MA 23123  
(67.11111,- 49.5567)"
131, Kyle, Engineer, 3A-bhbh, ,"Barnes St  
San Francisco, CA 34654  
(65.11111, 55.985432)"
```

Outputs:

```
field1," field1"," field3"," field4"," field5"," field6  "
111," John"," Doctor"," 1A-jrd"," ","(12.11111, 43.5555)"
121," Bob"," Teacher"," 2A-abcd",345,"(67.11111,- 49.5567)"
131," Kyle"," Engineer"," 3A-bhbh"," ","(65.11111, 55.985432)"
```

Hopefully it's clear how you could further modify 'field6' to meet your spec precisely.